# Passing value from Servlet to JSP

Tags: jsp

Im a newbie to JSP and have some questions on passing values from the Servlet to the JSP page that is rendered..

Currently, I get a list of actors from a table and create a new attribute in the request object and access the object in my JSP page..

Is there any other way way to pass the value from the servlet to JSP?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Im in actorsservlet");
        Actors acrs = new Actors();
        ArrayList<Actor> actorslist = null;
        try {
            actorslist = acrs.getactors();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Actor ac:actorslist)
            System.out.println(ac.firstname);
        request.setAttribute("actorslist", actorslist);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("getactors.jsp");
        //response.sendRedirect("getactors.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return;
```

Comment: Calling a servlet via Ajax perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your attribute to the session instead of the request. So let's see if I recall [correctly](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

```
session.setAttribute("actorslist", actorslist);
```

Something of note: this will allow you to access it from any jsp in your web app. But session variables can be tricky. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) for EL examples of accessing different scopes within your JSP.

It'll probably look something like:

```
${sessionScope.actorslist}    //<- the whole list
${sessionScope.actorslist[0]} //<- this first actor in the list
```

Good Luck. Happy Coding.

Comment: This will stay in memory for the duration of the session, unlike the request object.

Comment: While that is true, that decision depends entirely on the usage of this actorslist. For example, if it's being used across JSP pages. It also depends on the scope of this program. If it's just a quick prototype program or sample program to learn jsps, it seems silly to worry about memory.